# Converter JSON para Array no Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, json, highcharts

Boa tarde, é minha primeira pergunta aqui.

Estou recebendo o json abaixo através de uma requisição ajax.

```
[
    {"SEMANA":1.0,"PRODUCAO":0.0,"PRODUCAO2":0.0},
    {"SEMANA":2.0,"PRODUCAO":29280.0,"PRODUCAO2":55992.0},
    {"SEMANA":3.0,"PRODUCAO":93864.0,"PRODUCAO2":75072.0},    
    {"SEMANA":4.0,"PRODUCAO":135625.0,"PRODUCAO2":102480.0}
]
```

Faço a conversão do JSON para array dessa forma abaixo:

```
$.get("caminho do WebService", function (dados) {
    var arrSemana = [],
    arrProd1 = [],
    arrProd2 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) {
        arrSemana.push(dados[i].SEMANA);
        arrProd1.push(dados[i].PRODUCAO);
        arrProd2.push(dados[i].PRODUCAO2);
    }
    //......
});
```

Porem na hora que vou verificar esse meu `array (arrSemana, arrProd1, arrProd2)` fica assim `[,,,,,,,,]` e não com os valores assim como gostaria `[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]`

Estou criando gráficos com o **highChart** por isso preciso desse array.

Onde estou errando que ele não está pegando os valores conforme eu preciso?
Alguém tem algum exemplo que possa me ajudar?

Obrigado a atenção de todos.

Estou trabalhando com Apache Cordova (PhoneGap). Preciso colocar isso em 3 array para assim poder colocar no gráfico.

$(function () { $.get("caminho do WebService", function (dados) {

```
var arrSemana = [],
    arrProd1 = [],
    arrProd2 = [];

for (var i = 0; i < dados.length; i++) {
    arrSemana.push(dados[i].SEMANA);
    arrProd1.push(dados[i].PRODUCAO);
    arrProd2.push(dados[i].PRODUCAO2);
}
// Os alerts estão aqui para teste...
alert(dados);
alert(arrSemana);
alert(arrProd1);
alert(arrProd2);

$('#chart').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Produção semanal de açúcar (registrada)',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Dados: Teste de Relatório',
        x: -20
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Semanas'
        },
        categories: arrSemana, //Um array vem aqui...
        minTickInterval: 5,
        minRange: 0,
        min: 0
    },
    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        title: {
            text: 'Produção'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: 'un'
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'middle',
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Semanas 12/13',
        color: '#32CD32',
        data: arrProd1 // Outro array vem aqui...
    }, {
        name: 'Semanas 13/14',
        color: '#000000',
        data: arrProd2 // Outro array vem aqui...
    }]
});
```

}).fail(function () {
    alert("Erro ao carregar os dados do relatório.");
});
});[image: Essa imagem foi gerada fazendo o exemplo explicado abaixo...]

Comment: você não tem como enviar o array no formato correto?

Comment: Mas o array é o que não estou conseguindo montar. Você falou sobre o JSON será?

Esse é aquele que coloquei acima, está chegando exatamente assim, tanto que faço um alert(dados) dele e a imagem que exibe na tela é com esse valor.

Comment: O tipo do retorno (mimetype, contenttype) está correto? Se você chama `get` sem especificar um `dataType` o jQuery "adivinha" o formato correto com base no retorno do servidor. Você pode usar `getJSON` também. Fora isso, seu código parece correto. Você já tentou fazer `console.log(dados)` e ver se está tudo ok?

Comment: eu já utilizei o $.getJSON e aconteceu a mesma coisa, ai fiz dessa forma pra testar se seria diferente o resultado.

Comment: O seu codigo esta correto; http://jsbin.com/layojiqahu/1/edit?js,console da um console.log no `dados` e ve se esta retornando correto do servidor

Comment: Poisé eu tambem testei o codigo e parece correto: http://jsfiddle.net/3s8mrcb3/

Comment: @RafaelOliveira Se o código está correto e o tipo está correto, ou o problema está nos dados ou é na hora de você **usar** os valores. Se o `console.log` não mostrar nada de anormal, por favor poste o código onde você usa esses arrays.

Comment: Então foi isso que estranhei também. Ai fiquei confuso, porque parece correto. Vocês tem alguma outra ideia de como montar isso?

Comment: Estou indo embora agora, testarei amanhã e retorno aqui o resultado. Obrigado por enquanto.

Comment: @mgibsonbr postei meu código aqui...como estou trabalhando com o Apache Cordova (phonegap) não estou conseguindo testar o console.log, só consigo emular via dispositivo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sugiro usar o [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para fazer isso.

```js
var json = JSON.parse('[ {"SEMANA":1.0,"PRODUCAO":0.0,"PRODUCAO2":0.0}, {"SEMANA":2.0,"PRODUCAO":29280.0,"PRODUCAO2":55992.0}, {"SEMANA":3.0,"PRODUCAO":93864.0,"PRODUCAO2":75072.0}, {"SEMANA":4.0,"PRODUCAO":135625.0,"PRODUCAO2":102480.0} ]');

var arrays = ['SEMANA','PRODUCAO','PRODUCAO2'];
arrays = arrays.map(function(campo){
    var novoConteudo = json.map(function(objeto){
       return objeto[campo]; 
    });
    return novoConteudo;
});

alert(JSON.stringify(arrays));
```

O [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) parte de uma array e retorna uma array com o mesmo numero de elementos mas com novo conteudo. Assim partindo de `['SEMANA','PRODUCAO','PRODUCAO2']` fiz um primeiro `map()` que itera cada campo, dentro desde primeiro map crio outro map, que itera o JSON. Desse modo para cada array do JSON vou buscar só o "campo" que me interessa.

Repare que no seu JSON alguns campos vêm por exemplo `1.0` em numerico. Se não tiver isso em String então ele vai ser lido como somente `1`.

---

Se quiser ter uma variável para cada array pode fazer:

```
var arrSemana = arrays[0];
var arrProd1 = arrays[1];
var arrProd2 = arrays[2];
```

Comment: Mas eu preciso desses 3 arrays para montar o gráfico conforme o código completo que postei abaixo, dessa forma parece que ficará tudo em apenas um array. É isso mesmo?

Comment: @RafaelOliveira eu rodei o exemplo do Sergio, e aqui apareceram os 3 arrays que você precisa, certinho. Os 3 estão disponíveis dentro da variável `arrays`. Aí não deu o mesmo resultado?

Comment: Eu testei aqui, ele retornou sim os 3 arrays dentro de um pelo que parece. Como faço agora para selecionar só aquele que desejo para colocar cada um dos 3 nos seus lugares?Conforme o código que mostrei acima eu uso isso em highchart, e ai nele passo esses array. Tenho uma imagem do alert mostrado no android, onde posso adicionar para ficar exemplo?

Comment: Adicionei uma imagem do exemplo obtido na primeira pergunta que fiz acima.

Comment: Os 3 arrays que vc quer: `arrays[0]`, `arrays[1]` e `arrays[2]` ...

Comment: @RafaelOliveira juntei um exemplo no fim da resposta.